# C# code calls an IronPython script that imports two packages

Tags: c#, ironpython

My C# code calls an IronPython script that imports two packages.

My environment is:

- Installed IronPython 2.7.1 from GitHub.
- Installed Enthought's Python.
- I am using Visual Studio 2012 and C# 4.5 to develop my test project.
- I am running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 (x64).

I have also added
   the following references to my project:

```
   IronPython
   IronPython.Modules
   Microsoft Scripting
   Microsoft.Dynamic
```

My C# code is:

```
using System;
using IronPython.Hosting;
namespace RunExternalScript {
  internal class Program {
    private static void Main() {
      var py = Python.CreateEngine();
      try {
        py.ExecuteFile("script.py");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Oops! We couldn't execute the script because of an exception: " + ex.Message);
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

The Python script.py is:

```
import pickel
import numpy
print('Imports work.')
```

If I comment out the two imports, the program works.
My real script needs the "pickel" and "numpy" packages.

How can I get my Python script to import these two packages?

Charles

Answer (score 1):

You can tell IronPython that where to search for packages by using `PythonEngine.SetSearchPaths(...)` function.

For Example

```
var py = Python.CreateEngine();
private List<string> m_searchPaths = new List<string>();
m_searchPaths.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Lib");
m_searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python27\lib");
// Add any other Path you want to add in search path
py.SetSearchPaths(m_searchPaths);
try
{
    py.ExecuteFile("script.py");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Oops! We couldn't execute the script because of an exception: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I added two search paths, and the "import" message went away.  However, I now get: "Oops! We couldn't execute the script because of an exception: No module named __future__".  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hope Adding `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Lib"` in search path solves this issue